# How to collapse closing parenthesis to the same line as the opening parenthesis in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I collapse a function in VS Code, the closing parentheses are still visible:
[image]

I would love to have them collapsed as they do in Visual Studio:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the subject of a very popular feature request issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo: [[folding] Collapse ending brace to the same line
#3352](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3352) <sup><sub>(full of the hallmark mass of annoying "me too" comments (please don't join them))</sub></sup>. Amidst the noise of all the annoying "me too" comments there, you'll see a link to the actionable information you want in another issue ticket: [Hide FoldRange end line #111731](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111731). The TL;DR of that issue ticket's thread is that this kind of functionality is implemented on a per-language-extension basis. VS Code's default behaviour in the absence of a language extension is to provide folding facilities based on indentation. In the presence of a language extension, it's up to that language extension to implement [`FoldingRangeProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FoldingRangeProvider). So you need to file a request or Pull Request to the maintainers specific language extension that you want such behaviour / configurable behaviour for.